# Помогите разобраться с NSURLSession

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Вот код:

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration:NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print("Test!")
}
```

Почему-то не доходит до строки print("Test!")
т.е. ничего не выводится в Playground
Учить swift только начал, пытаюсь получить данные с сервера!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) session после создания находится в состоянии suspended, и чтоб его запустить надо выполнить

```
task.resume()
```

2) судя по всему есть какие то ограничения на работу сессий в плейграунде. Мне так и не удалось запустить ваш код в плейграунде, хотя в обычном проекте все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось добавить еще в info.plist следующие 2 строки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]